# How to integrate a C++ project with NodeJS using CMake

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, build, cmake

I have a project that is written in cross-platform C++ that I have been working on for a long time using Visual Studio to compile and debug.

My project includes a C++ library as well as executables for the library

Within the last year I wrote some cross-platform build scripts using CMake and Python. I have decided that I would also like to use my project as a NodeJS C++ addon, so I have abandoned CMake if favor of GYP to work with `node-gyp`.

GYP is working great for my projects as well as integration with NodeJS, however I also need to get Google Test working with my project again, which uses CMake.

I have been researching this problem for a long time, and do not have a clear direction to go. I could restore the previous CMake/Python build system I had before, but I would have no idea how to continue supporting integration with NodeJS.

I am wondering if there is a solution that will allow me to easily integrate with NodeJS, as well as other projects. I also intend to integrate with the V8 engine, which uses the GN build system.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Maybe [CMake.js](https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js) could be a good option. Never used it myself though.

Comment: @super that definitely seem like a good option for integration with NodeJS using CMake! If I go with this, my only future question will be about integration V8 with CMake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Going with CMake.js (https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js) thanks to @super